# space allocation for a number of strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Hi I am trying to get a space for storing a number of words.
My plan is to use a two-dimension array, which stores a string.
It looks like this:

```
pBuffer[0]---------->myBuffer[0][0] myBuffer[0][1]...
pBuffer[1]---------->myBuffer[1][0] myBuffer[1][1]...
..
```

However, it gets error and I am struggling to debug this. 
What's the problem?

#### 1. Declaration

```
char myBuffer[255][255];
char* pBuffer[255];
```

#### 2. Usage

```
char* pBuffer[i] = &myBuffer[i][0];
pStream->cmdArray[i].u.word = &pBuffer[i];
strcpy(*pStream->cmdArray[i].u.word, infix_string);
i++;
```

#### 3. Error & Warning

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
  char* pBuffer[i] = &myBuffer[i][0];
  ^
warning: unused variable 'pBuffer' [-Wunused-variable]
   char* pBuffer[255];
```

Comment: put entire code, please update your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* pBuffer[i] = &myBuffer[i][0];
```

Remove the leading "char*", the compiler thinks you're trying to declare a new variable called pBuffer which "shadows" the original definition of pbuffer.

```
char* pBuffer[255]; // declares pbuffer as an array of 255 char* pointers
char* pBuffer[i];   // illegal and, if it worked, would be a shadow declaration.
```

Comment: If you're using a faintly modern version of C (not the 23+ year old version but the 13+ year old version — C99, or the more recent C11), then the `char *pBuffer[i];` declaration is a valid VLA (variable length array) definition, assuming `i` is an integer variable (or a name for an integer constant, but then it isn't VLA any more).  But you can't provide any initializer for a VLA, as the compiler error message indicates.

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote something weird. It should just be `pBuffer[i] = &myBuffer[i][0];`, in a loop of course.